# Java groovy stream to compare two lists and return single boolean variable

Tags: java, groovy, java-stream

I am trying to compare the properties of elements inside two different lists and return a single boolean variable if all of them matched. I am trying to do this in groovy.

```
def "Test1"() {
    given:
    ...

    when:
    ...

    then: "Compare results"
    IntStream.range(0, 2).allMatch((index) -> packagesMatch(requests.get(index), responses.get(index)));
}

private boolean packagesMatch(Request request, Response response) {
    boolean match = (request.property1 == response.property1)
    match = match && (request.property2 == response.property2)
    match = match && (request.property3 == response.property3)
    match = match && (request.property4 == response.property4)
    return match
}
```

The above code is giving a compilation error at ->: "Groovyc: unexpected token: ->". Hovering the mouse pointer on that line is giving a hint:

```
<expression> or '=' expected, got '->'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groovy uses its `{ }` closure syntax. That said, it seems that what you really want to do is this:

```
then:
(0..2).every { packagesMatch(requests[it], responses[it]) }
```

or even:

```
then:
[requests, responses].transpose().every { request, response -> packagesMatch(request, response) }
```

(There might be a still better way to phrase it depending on what your real types are. And your `packagesMatch` can be, guessing also that your `property` names aren't actually sequentially numbered:

```
return ["property1", "property2"].every { request."$it" == response."$it" }
```

)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Apart from adding the curly braces, I had to remove the normal braces around index as well to make it compile: IntStream.range(0, 2).allMatch({index -> packagesMatch(assignRequests.get(index), response.packages.get(index))});

Comment: @Romonov If you're going to use Groovy, it's worth learning some of its idioms, because it can help you write much simpler code than a direct translation from (verbose) Java; `(0..2).every` is exactly the same as `IntStream.range(0, 2).allMatch`